# How to get selective rows in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I've increasing values from a random number like `2,3,5,8` and then again it starts from some number like`4,5,6,7` and then starts again from some number like `1,2,3,4,6`

so I have data in this arrangement `2,3,5,8,4,5,6,7,1,2,3,4,6 (single column)`.

Now, what I want is, I want to get the highest value in each sequence. In the given data, I want rows with values 8 for first data items, 7 for second and 6 for third. So I need three rows in the above data.

What kind of query I need to write? Or I need a cursor?

Comment: Show us the table definition.

Comment: consider it a single column table the column is of type integer. Each value will have a time stamp, but I don't have a group by column (a column with same items for a sequence) :|

Answer (score 1):

I assume following table definition

```
CREATE TABLE sequence (
sequence_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
sequence_item INTEGER NOT NULL
);
```

Use this query to get highest value for each sequence:

```
SELECT sequence_id, max(sequence_item)
FROM sequence
GROUP BY sequence_id
```

Assuming following table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE `sequence` (
  `t` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `sequence_item` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`t`)
);
```

where by 'sequence' We assume each continuous sequence of sequence_item rows that are in `t` order - refer to author comment below if You don't get it;)

You can get maximum number in sequence using (omit sid in SELECT to get just max numbers):

```
set @sid = 1;
set @prev = (SELECT sequence_item-1 FROM sequence ORDER BY t LIMIT 1);

SELECT sid, MAX(sequence_item)
FROM (
SELECT
    @prev,
    IF(@prev != (sequence_item-1), (@sid:=@sid+1),@sid) as 'sid',
    sequence_item, t, @prev:=sequence_item
FROM sequence
ORDER BY t) as sitems
group by sid
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, but unfortunately, I don't have a column on which I can "group by". Each row has a different value for every column :(

Comment: Then how do You determine which row belongs to which sequence? You must determine it somehow because according to SQL standard following query may return rows in ANY order (not necessary in order in which values where inserted into table): SELECT sequence_item FROM sequence.

Comment: I've timestamp on which I can order by, but no column on which I can group by :(